# Get a list of user profiles on machine local and domain

Tags: windows

Is there a way, either by PowerShell, batch, C# to get a list of all the profiles currently on the local machine. I need to collect a list of profiles and show whether they are local users, or domain users, and what domain they belong too.

As shown in the screenshot below, Microsoft has the "User Profiles" window, which is exactly what I'm looking for, except I'd like to automate it and get it either from a script or something.

I have not been able to find anything that does both.

I've tried doing a mix of getting local profile info via WMI or through the registry to get the information.

I've used both

> win32_UserProfile

and

> win32_UserAccount

However, UserProfile only gives me the paths to userprofiles, no domain information. UserAccount returns all of AD, even when trying to filter it out by SID, but takes far to long.

```
PS>Get-WmiObject -Class win32_userprofile | select localpath, SID

localpath                                 SID                                            
---------                                 ---                                            
C:\Users\TestUser1                        S-1-5-21-440147649-543696746-2340718013-21890  
C:\Users\Admin                            S-1-5-21-4226746363-32877083-2456121708-500    
C:\Users\TestUser2                        S-1-5-21-1876808186-3675847616-1704270002-46278
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService S-1-5-20                                       
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService   S-1-5-19                                       
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile  S-1-5-18
```

My next attempt was to use the information from WMI and load the users registry hives and get what domain they are on from there, however I could not find any useful information when the users registry hive is loaded. I did notice that if the current user was logged in there is a key in there for "Volatile Environment" (screenshot below), which has all the information I need, but is only available when that user is currently logged in, not loading the hive manually.

Where else can I look for this information?

Current User, volatile environment:

[image]

Windows User Profile Dialog:

[image]

Comment: Is this possible: it absolutely is possible.  So what have you tried? We are not a script writing service. Edit your question and don’t indicate you have tried nothing.

Comment: I'm not asking for a script to be written, but just to be pointed in the right direction. As I stated I've tried getting the information from WMI and the registry, and those don't seem to have the information I'm looking for, I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: We won’t be able to point you in that direction without you at least walking in a direction.  The solution to your problem is you query the local users that exist on the machine then query the domain users that exist on the machine.  You then combine the two lists